# How to create an api like this 'GET host:///api?user.username=bug' in Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, backend, restful-url, spring-hateoas

**I saw this kind of API style once and it worked proper**

**Noob here and I am current learning RESTful stuff,If anyone who may gives some advice and instruction.I'd be very appreciate!**

*Get URL*

```
//The argument isn't mandatory, May be order.orderInfo,order.orderPrice etc

http://localhost:8080/order?order.orderNo=123
```

*Controller code*

```
    @GetMapping
    CollectionModel<Order> getOrders(Order order) {
    List<Order> ordersResult = orderService.getOrders(order);

    for (Order result : ordersResult) {
        Link selfLink = WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(OrderController.class).slash(result.getId()).withSelfRel();
        result.add(selfLink);
    }

    Link link = WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(OrderController.class).withSelfRel();

    return CollectionModel.of(ordersResult, link);
}
```

*Entity code*

```
public class Order extends RepresentationModel<Order> implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(unique = true)
private Integer id;

private Long orderNo;
}
```

*And my jpa repository*

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Integer>,PagingAndSortingRepository<Order, Integer> {
```

}

Comment: #1 dot in your field name order.orderNo=123 is mandatory? #2 if your endpoint /order just receive one field, why are you mapping two arguments in your spring method? #3 If you just need to receive the order id to use it in your internal logic, why do you complicate your life?

Comment: @JRichardsz #1 No,I wanna this api could be flexable.For example,In the furture,The order extends to have mult elements.At the front-end,Developer could use any one of the fileds as the filter condition.'order.orderInfo' etc.#2 Sorry the second arg is for my test if the mapping for check the getmapping correct worked~#3Same to the 1 reason.I want recevie any field of Object to make me feature came true use 'JPA.exampleof()'. Thank you!

Comment: #1 points for your idea to make a flexable api. #2 If you are working in an api, you should use [http methods in restfull apis](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html). #3 On my case if the endpoint is a crud I use http methods but if is an endpoint who could receive any parameter, I use a post method with a body like a query. Would you see it ? #3 If you have a map of all the query parameters of your endpoint /order, I would help you?

Comment: @JRichardsz Thanks dude.I had just figured out why we need this kind of url.It is not flexable and you right,If I I want to build an flexable api.I shoud follow HTTP protocal.In this case we shall use '#fragment'.'obj.filed=xxx' This kind of url shoud apply to a get method that paramter object contains 'obj'.Then it will work.Sorry My bad English.At the end,Thank you for you help,It was helpful and inspired me.

Answer (score 0):

**I have finally figured out that this kind of URL is not work this way.**

**Shoud be apply to a specific situation.Which is the get endpoint method has a 'Relative Object'.Then we may use URL like this to improve flexable api.**

***Talk is cheap,I'll show you the code!***

Entity->Customer

```
public class Customer extends RepresentationModel<Customer> implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(unique = true)
private Integer id;

private String name;

//Add relative Object to entity.
@OneToOne
private Order order;
}
```

Entity->Order

```
public class Order extends RepresentationModel<Order> implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(unique = true)
private Integer id;

private Long orderNo;

//Add relative Object to entity.
@OneToOne
private Customer customer;
}
```

Endpoint->CustomerController/getMethod

```
    @GetMapping
    CollectionModel<Customer> getCustomers(Customer customer) {
    List<Customer> customersResult = 
     customerService.getCustomers(customer);

    for (Customer result : customersResult) {
        Link selfLink = WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(CustomerController.class).slash(result.getId()).withSelfRel();
        result.add(selfLink);
    }

    Link link = WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(CustomerController.class).withSelfRel();

    return CollectionModel.of(customersResult, link);
    }
```

URL

```
scheme://[api]/[order.orderNo=123]
```

Then the value will mapping to paramter-custoemr inside.

PS:HTTP method '#fragment' may suitable for this case.

Thanks to @JRichardsz :)

Comment: Great job. Also If you want to avoid to create several endpoints, one by each requested query, you could take a look to these [frameworks](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/9c32f9c43c841ada28117f30e1bf34ed)

Comment: @JRichardsz Added to my readlist,Thx anyway!